# PHP / Wordpress - SQLSRV Unstable Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, openvpn, sqlsrv

I am working on a php/wordpress project that requires a connection to a sql server.
The connection to the database server works but not every time, it is often that I have to try and send the request again in order for it to return the needed response. I do not have access to sql server configuration, but I have asked the people responsible for it to take a look and they told me that everything is working fine on their end. The server is also protected by a VPN and I was wondering if this could be the issue ?

Here are the errors that are returned by sqlsrv when the attempted request has failed:

```
SQLSTATE: HYT00
code: 0
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
SQLSTATE: 08001
code: -1
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
SQLSTATE: 08001
code: -1
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

On other occasions I get these:

```
SQLSTATE: 01000
code: 5701
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to '*******'.
SQLSTATE: 01000
code: 5703
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
```

Like I said sometimes the connection works and sometimes it does not, is there a way to make it more reliable ?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess two questions come to mind: 1) are you trying to use SQL Server's connection encryption over a VPN connection (which itself is already encrypted), and 2) what type of VPN connection is it? Attempting to tunnel TCP-based SSL/TLS protocols over (a lot of) older TCP-based VPN protocols can lead to frequent delays and connection aborts. SQL Server's TDS protocol was designed for operation on LANs and already doesn't perform well over open internet connections due to increased latency.

Comment: Considering that Wordpress uses MySQL, by default, I assume this means that you are either: 1. Using a different built of Wordpress (such as Project Nami) that uses SQL Server 2. Altering the Wordpress files yourself to use SQL Server instead. If this isn't true for either of these, then that would suggest you're using the normal build of Wordpress, which expects a MySQL instance; it doesn't work with SQL Server out of the box..

Comment: Thank you for answering,

I am not all that familiar with all of this but to answer your first question I am not trying to use SQL Server's connection encryption.

I am using OpenVPN client so SSL/TLS-based, I do not have access to the VPN configuration but from what I understand based on your answer there is a possibility that this could be the cause of the unstable connection? What should I ask the person responsible for configuring the VPN?

Comment: I am not using the SQL Server with Wordpress, I only need to access it to fetch some data and perform actions on the wordpress site with this data.